# C++ - Don't get result after flush std::cout

Tags: c++, io, stl, std

```
using namespace std;
string str{ "text" };
stringstream ss{ str };
cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
cout.flush(); //cout<<endl;
```

This code is expected to print **text**,but showing **nothing**.

I associate **ss** to **stdout** then flush it,but I don't know why it didn't work even if I refer to many illustration.

```
cout<<rdbuf(ss);
```

this is OK but where's the different? : (

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstood this concept. The line

```
cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
```

sets the pointer to the buffer. It redirects `cout` to `ss` and not to console. If you write into `cout` it will be written to `ss`.

I hope this clears it for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::streambuf *backup;

    backup = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    std::cout.rdbuf(backup);
    std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
    return 0;
}
```

In the example code I create a copy of the current pointer of `cout`'s buffer. Next I redirect the `cout` to `ss`. When I write into `cout` it is written into `ss`'s buffer. Next I redirect `cout` back to console and print the content of `ss`.

If you want to manipulate the buffer you need somethink like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss{ "test" };
    std::stringbuf *pbuf = ss.rdbuf();
    char buffer[80];
    pbuf->sgetn (buffer,80);
    std::streambuf *pbuf2 = std::cout.rdbuf();
    pbuf2->sputn (buffer, std::strlen(buffer));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I know why I misunderstood it  . rdbuf == redirect_buffer , rdbuf != read_buffer. thank you !

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @Thomas Sablik answer, here is a code example for printing "text" by redirecting streams:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
ss << "text";
std::cout.flush();
```

If you want to copy the content of `ss`'s streambuf to `std::cout`, you can use inserter directly:

```
std::string str{ "text" };
std::stringstream ss{ str };
std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
std::cout.flush();
```

http://wordaligned.org/articles/cpp-streambufs